# Обрезать нули после точки с конца на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Каким образом обрезать все нули после точки **с конца**?

Моё регулярное выражение не работает:

```
'1.00030000'.replace(/\.0{1,}$/, '');
```

Однако работает так, но естественно неверно, так как нужно после точки:

```
'1.00030000'.replace(/0{1,}$/, '');
```

Нужно чтобы получилось **1.0003**

Comment: Что должно получиться?

Comment: @Alexey Ten, 1.0003

Comment: Значит можно захватить всё что между точкой и нулями `'1.00030000'.replace(/(\.[0-9]+?)0{1,}$/, '$1');`

Comment: @andreymal, если например взять число 1000.0040, то оставляет только 1000, а надо чтобы последние нули просто обрезало.

Comment: @ModaL я проверил, получается `1000.004` точно как вы хотите

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает второй вариант который у вас написан?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log(Number(1.00030000));
//или
console.log('1.00030000'.replace(/(?<=\.[0-9]+)0{1,}$/, ''));
```

Comment: Даёт неправильный результат при значении `9876543210123456789.010` например

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log('1.00030000'.replace(/(\.\d*?)0+$/, '$1'));
```

`\d*?` - любое количество цифр, с ленивым квантификатором (`*?`): в противоположность дефолтному жадному поведению (захват как можно большей части строки), он захватывает минимальное количество символов. А не останавливаться на первом же подходящем символе, его вынуждает следующий далее токен `0+` с признаком конца текста `$`.